# How to derive fixed end moment of a beam fixed at both ends with a point force not in the center

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis, structures, moments

[image]

So this is as far as I have gotten. The formulas written in green are the formulas that I have to find/ derive but I am hitting a wall. I know I am supposed to integrate but I am not sure where to go from here to get to the end formulas. If someone could please help explain/ walk me through this, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. The way I'd solve it, is the following.

I would break your problem in two subproblems right next to the application of the  force F (at point K which is at a distance $x=a^+$).

[image]

In that case, there compliance constraints that should be met. I.e. the point K is common at both problem 1 and problem 2, so:

- The shear forces at $x=a^+$ for problem 1 (i.e.  $Q_1(a^+)$ or $Q_{K;1}$) and problem 2 (i.e. $Q_2(a^+)$ or  or $Q_{K;2}$) should be equal. (Eventually this will not be used but its for the sake of completeness).

$$Q_{K;1}= Q_{K;2}$$

- The bending moments at $x=a^+$ for problem 1 (i.e.  $M_1(a^+)$ or $M_{K;1}$) and problem 2 (i.e. $M_2(a^+)$ or  or $M_{K;2}$) should be equal.

$$M_1(K;2) = M_{K;2}$$

- The angle at $x=a^+$ for problem 1 (i.e.  $\dot{y}_1(a^+)$) and problem 2 (i.e. $\dot{y}_2(a^+)$) should be equal.

$$\dot{y}_1(a^+) = \dot{y}_2(a^+)$$

- The displacement at $x=a^+$ for problem 1 (i.e. $y_1(a^+)$) and problem 2 (i.e. $y_2(a^+)$) should be equal.

$$y_1(a^+) = y_2(a^+)$$

So right now from the original problem you had 4 unknowns ($M_A, R_A, M_B, R_B$) and two equations (equilibrium $\sum F_x, \sum M$). By breaking the problem up you are introducing two more unknowns (the internal reactions at point K, i.e. $Q_K, M_K$) and you have 4 more additional constraints.  Therefore this is a system of 6 equation with 6 unknowns.

### Solving the system

I am not keen in performing the mathematics ( especially for problem 2 there is a tricky part depending on how you obtain the coordinate system), so I will perform only problem 1, for you.

### Problem 1

To revise, problem 1 will look like :

[image]

Therefore you have:

- $Q_1(x)= \begin{cases} R_A & 0<x<a\\
  -F+R_A & a<x<a+
  \end{cases}$
- $M_1(x)= \begin{cases} -M_A +R_A x & 0<x<a\\
  -M_A +R_A x - F\cdot (x-a) & a<x<a+
  \end{cases}$
- $\dot{y}_(K_1) $ this will be calculated from
  $$EI y_1'' = M_1(x)$$
  by integrating
  $$\int_0^{a^+} EI y_1'' dx = \int_0^{a^+}M_1(x)dx$$

$$ EI \int_0^{a^+} y_1''dx = \int_0^{a^+}M_1(x)dx$$

because $a^+$ is infinitesimally close to a and , $\int_0^{a} y_1''dx= y_1'(a)=  y'_{K;1} $ we can write

$$ EI y'_{K;1} = \int_0^{a}M_1(x)dx$$
$$ EI y'_{K;1} = \int_0^{a}( -M_A +R_A x)dx$$
$$ EI y'_{K;1} =  \left[-M_A x +\frac{R_A}{2} x^2\right]_0^a$$
Finally:
$$y'_{K;1} =  \frac{1}{EI}\left(-M_A a+\frac{R_A}{2} a^2\right)$$

- For the deflection of the beam at point K  using a similar approach
  $$\int_0^{a^+} \left(\int_0^{a^+} EI y_1'' dx \right)dx= \int_0^{a^+} \left(\int_0^{a^+}M_1(x)dx\right)dx$$

$$ y_{K;1}= \frac{1}{EI}\int_0^{a} \left( -M_A x +\frac{R_A}{2} x^2 \right)dx$$
$$ y_{K;1}= \frac{1}{EI} \left[ -\frac{M_A}{2} x^2 +\frac{R_A}{6} x^3 \right]_0^a$$
$$ y_{K;1}= \frac{1}{EI} \left( -\frac{M_A}{2} a^2 +\frac{R_A}{6} a^3 \right)$$

### Problem 2

The way we broke up the problem (at $a^+$) simplifies the equation for the second par.  The tricky part about problem two is that you integrating from a to L.

[image]

- $Q_2(x)= -R_B $ for $ a<x\le L$
- $M_2(x)= -M_B+ R_B\cdot(L-x) $ for $ a<x\le L$
- $\dot{y}_(K_2) $ this will be calculated from
  $$EI y_2'' = M_2(x)$$
  then
  $$\int_{a^+}^L EI y_2'' dx = \int{a^+}^L M_2(x)dx$$

Here, because $y_2'(x=a+ )=y'_{K;2}$ and $y_2'(x=a)=0$ you obtain
$$EI (0 - y'_{K;2}) = \int_{a}^L -M_B+ R_B\cdot(L-x)  dx$$

$$ y'_{K;2} = -\frac{1}{EI}\int_{a}^L -M_B+ R_B\cdot(L-x)  dx$$
$$ y'_{K;2} = -\frac{1}{EI}\left[ -M_B x+ R_B\cdot(L x-\frac{x^2}{2})  \right]_{a}^L$$
$$ y'_{K;2} = -\frac{1}{EI}\left(\left( -M_B L+ R_B\cdot(L^2-\frac{L^2}{2})  \right) - 
\left( -M_B a+ R_B\cdot(L a-\frac{a^2}{2})  \right)\right)$$

There is another step with the displacement, which I am not keen to go through (I leave it as an exercise to the interested reader).

### System of equation from constraints

Going back to the constraints you should get for

- The shear forces at $x=a^+$ .

$$Q_{K;1}= Q_{K;2} \rightarrow -F+R_A =  -R_B $$

- The bending moments .

$$M_1(K;2) = M_{K;2}  \rightarrow  -M_A +R_A a= -M_B+ R_B\cdot(L-a)$$

- The angle at $x=a^+$ .

$$\dot{y}_1(a^+) = \dot{y}_2(a^+)$$

$$\frac{1}{EI}\left(-M_A a +\frac{R_A}{2} a^2\right)
=
 -\frac{1}{EI}\left(\left( -M_B L+ R_B\cdot(L^2-\frac{L^2}{2})  \right) - 
\left( -M_B a+ R_B\cdot(L a-\frac{a^2}{2})  \right)\right)$$

- The displacement at $x=a^+$ for problem 1 (i.e. $y_1(a^+)$) and problem 2 (i.e. $y_2(a^+)$) should be equal.

$$y_1(a^+) = y_2(a^+)\rightarrow$$

$$ \frac{1}{EI} \left( -\frac{M_A}{2} a^2 +\frac{R_A}{6} a^3 \right) = \text{what ever you derive from the integration for }y_2(a^+) $$

So finally you have 5 equations with 5 unknowns ($Q_{K;1}$ is not used) and you solve the system.

### final solution

What you should get (if all the above is done correctly):

[image]

Comment: You don't have to reaccept my answer. You can just upvote the answers you feel have contributed.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the more elegant/classic method presented above, here is a practical, and simpler, method to derive the fixed end moments, using the concept of "consistent displacement" and "superposition". It can be used to verify the solutions obtained from the classic approach.

**1) The assumptions and information from simply supported beam:**

[image]

**2) The process:**

[image]

Note, you can expand the terms in the numerator and further reduce each formula to a more simple form. I'll leave it to you to do the exercises.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Translational]

[image: Rotational]

[image: Algebra]

The equations found do match the equations above, they are just written differently but will yield the same outcome.